# Unable to cleanse scraped content completely in Php

Tags: php, html, regex, utf-8, web-scraping

I'm trying to scrape the price of IKEA products according to the item's Article number. So the user is given a form and all that is required is to copy/paste the article number and the result should return the price of the item.

The issue I'm having is that I am also scraping the EURO (€) symbol, and try as I might I cannot seem to remove it completely.

On Chrome it appears to be gone but when testing in on firefox or microsoft edge it still appears.

The reason I need it gone is that I want to add a function that will return the price of the items if the quantity is larger than one, something which I cannot do while the string I'm scraping includes the Euro sign.

```
<html >
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="css/styles.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
<form method="get" action="calcprocess.php">
    <label for="name">Enter Product Number</label>
    <input type="text" name="product_number" required>
    <input type="submit">
</form>
```

Above is the code I use for the user to input the article code

```
<?php
if (isset($_GET['product_number'])) {
//url
    $url = "http://www.ikea.com/it/it/catalog/products/";
//    Product Number
    $product = $_GET['product_number'];
//    removes the fullstops in the product number
    $product = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '', $product);
//    Search the html of the page for the Name of the product
    $keyword_name = "name";
//    Search the html of the page for the Price of the product
    $keyword_price = "price1";
//    Return the URL of the desired product
    $item = $url . $product;
    echo $item;
    /**
     * Downloads a web page from $url, selects the the element by $id
     * and returns it's xml string representation.
     */
    function getElementByIdAsString($url, $id, $pretty = true)
    {
        $doc = new DOMDocument();
        @$doc->loadHTMLFile($url);

        if (!$doc) {
            throw new Exception("Failed to load $url");
        }

        // Obtain the element
        $element = $doc->getElementById($id);

        if (!$element) {
            throw new Exception("An element with id $id was not found");
        }

        if ($pretty) {
            $doc->formatOutput = true;
        }

        // Return the string representation of the element
        return $doc->saveXML($element);
    }
//    Obtain the price
    $item_cost = getElementByIdAsString($item,$keyword_price) ;
//    Strips the Euro sign
    $symbols = array('$', '€', '£', 'â¬Â', '&euro', "\xE2\x82\xAc", "&nbsp;", "Â");
    $item_cost = str_replace($symbols,'',$item_cost);
//    $item_cost = preg_replace('/[^a-z0-9]+/i', '', $item_cost);
    echo $item_cost;
//    Problem HERE :::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::: Euro symbol not being removed, Cannot multiply item cost by quantity
    $totalcost = $item_cost + $item_cost;
    echo $totalcost

    ?>

    <table class="calctable">
        <tr id="calchead">
            <th>Item Code</th>
            <th>Product Name</th>
            <th>Price</th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><?php echo $product;?></td>
            <td><?php echo getElementByIdAsString($item,$keyword_name);?></td>
            <td><?php echo "&euro".$item_cost;?></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    </div>
    </body>
    </html>
    <?php


}?>
```

I've tried str_replace, preg_replace but neither of these are completely removing the Euro symbol according to firefox. The result I'm getting is this:

```
http://www.ikea.com/it/it/catalog/products/70103349 Â 119,90 0
Item Code   Product Name    Price
70103349    
MALM
    â‚¬ Â 119,90
```

To be clear, my question is how to completely cleanse the Euro symbol when scraping the site so that I can run mathematical calculations on the value. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Rather than scrape the web pages, why don't you access the Ikea API? (e.g. http://www.ikea.com/us/en/catalog/products/S29011673/?type=xml&amp;dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes)

Comment: Don't have much experience using APIs, could you point me in the right direction?

Comment: OK, here's the API link for your [MALM product](http://www.ikea.com/it/it/catalog/products/70103349/?type=xml&amp;dataset=normal,allImages,prices,attributes). The returned data is XML, and you can find the pricing info under prices; the `unformatted` attribute is particlarly useful

Comment: In my code I am reaching the price by using the function getElementByIdAsString, what should I use to parse this XML result and find the unformatted attribute?